# Question about the meaning of finite complement topology.

Tags: general-topology

I want to eventually show that the "[finite complement topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness)" is in fact a topology. But first I want to make sure I understand the definition. My book says:

> Let X be an infinite set. Show that $\mathscr{T}_1=\{U \subseteq X : U = \emptyset $ or $ X\setminus U $ is finite $ \}$

note: It seems very paradoxical, to me, to say $U$ is $X \setminus U$. That is like saying "$U$ is not $U$". Then I found on wikipedia "a cofinite subset of a set X is a subset A whose complement in X is a finite set. In other words, A contains all but finitely many elements of X. "

So I want to be sure that I'm understanding what this means; writing a couple specific examples:

(1) If $X = \{1,2,3...\}$, then some examples of $U$ would be 

(a){2,3,4...} because the complement is {1}

(b){5,6,7...} because the complement is {1,2,3,4}

(b){1,3,5,7}$\cup${9,10,11...} because the complement is {2,4,6,8}

Or

(2) If $X = (0,10)$, then some examples of $U$ would be 

(a)(0,1)$\cup$(1,10) because the complement is {1}

(b)(0,1)$\cup$(1,2)$\cup$(2,3)$\cup$(3,4)$\cup$(4,10) because the complement is {1,2,3,4}

Or

(3) If $X =  \mathbb{R} ^2$ , then some examples of $U$ would be

(a) $U$ = points without integer coordinates OR any point with coordinates greater than 10, because the complement would be points with integers that are less than 10.

I know that none of those are complete list, but are those examples correct? Is it even possible to write a complete list of $U$'s for any given set?

Before I even begin this proof, I want to be sure I understand what is being asked.

Comment: The definition does not equate $U$ and $X\setminus U$. It says $U$ is open iff $U=\emptyset$ or if $X\setminus U$ is finite.

Comment: In  (1), (2) you use $\cap$ where you probably mean $\cup$. In (3) the complement of  the set of points without integer coordinates is infinite.

Comment: yes, i did mean $\cup$, i just made the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, those are all correct. Note that nowhere in the definition is it said that $U$ is the same as $X \backslash U$. The definition is saying that the open sets of the topology are precisely 1) the empty set, and 2) those subsets of $X$ whose complements are finite. That's why it's called the *finite complement topology.* Then it becomes straightforward to verify the definition of topology using DeMorgan's laws. Your intuition for why it is a topology is as follows: finite unions of finite sets are still finite, and so are infinite intersections.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition: you could define a topology by what its closed sets are (instead of its open sets) and check the axioms for those.

This is a bit more natural for this topology: the closed sets are exactly all finite subsets of $X$ and $X$ itself (which is not finite, but must be closed in any topology).

Then the axioms for closed sets are quite clear: they must be closed under intersections (which is clear, as the set $X$ does nothing in intersections, and if one set in the intersection is finite, so will the intersection be) and finite unions (also clear).